# Oracle 11g express install on Linux

Tags: linux, oracle-11g

Do I have to be root user to install Oracle 11g on RHEL 6.5 (Santiago)?

I am able to install the rpm as a different user, rpm2cpio oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm | cpio -idv

But when I run

```
. ./oracle-xe configure (must be root user to run the configure script.)
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes you do in this case - it should give you a message after installing the RPM that this must be done (see below)

```
rpm -ivh oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]  
   1:oracle-xe              ########################################### [100%]  
Executing post-install steps...  
You must run '/etc/init.d/oracle-xe configure' as the root user to configure the database.
```